# why does this code returns a "None" when sorting using lambda?

Tags: python

I was trying to sort this but it returned none..

```
some_authors = ["Isaac Asimov", "Ray Bradbury", "Sin Johny", "Big Dinggus", "Big Chunggos","H.G Wels", "H.P Lovecraft"]

print(some_authors.sort(key=lambda name: name.split(" ")[-1].lower()))
```

Result:None

Comment: Because `sort` returns `None`. Sort the list and than print it.

Comment: The `sort` method don't return any value (which is the same as returning None in python) since it sort the list directly so the list object itself is sorted. You can try to use the `sorted(some_authors)` method instead, which will create a copy of the list sort it and return the copy so the result will no longer be None.

Answer (score 4):

`list.sort()` sorts in-place. It doesn't return anything. [In-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) means that the list itself gets transformed, there is no new list generated.

Source: The official documentation of `list.sort()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

Just sort then print.

```
some_authors.sort(key=lambda name: name.split(" ")[-1].lower())
print(some_authors)
```

This is a good reminder of why you should always consult documentation before posting here, 9 times out of 10 the documentation will have the answer.

Also, as a bonus, there's a function [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) which would do what you want. The documentation for `sort()` says:

> use `sorted()` to explicitly request a new sorted list instance

So, your code could look like this if you used `sorted()`:

```
print(sorted(some_authors, key=lambda name: name.split(" ")[-1].lower()))
```

Comment: /me notes the bullet point about questions that "have been asked and answered many times before" in the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)